# Updating a run list in chef using knife

Tags: ruby, knife, chef-infra

I have cookbook which contains a list of recipes. What is the command to add some specific recipes (not all) from cookbook using command line tool in chef `knife`?

I know the command to add the whole cookbook to run list which is `knife node run_list add server name recipe[cookbook name]`.

Comment: Please update your tags, Ruby is not the only technology involved here. Also improve your question by explaining a little more, that won't hurt.

Comment: this is my first question. so didn't knew much.

Comment: That's ok, we're here to help. The title is too long (I can't change it for you, I have no idea what you're talking about, but something like *Updating a list in Chef (knife) using the command line* seems nice). Put the explanations and the exact question in the content.

Comment: There should be minimal example code replicating what you're asking about, sample input data and the expected output data. Without those things we have to imagine your code, which seldom works well, generate data to fit the imaginary code, and hope that the output is what you want. That doesn't really suit Stack Overflow too well, so help us by supplying the information we need to help you. See "[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" for more information.

Answer (score 13):

So you have the right idea, `knife node run_list add $nodename $item` is the command you want.

`recipe[mycookbook]` doesn't add "the whole cookbook", instead that is just a shorthand for `recipe[mycookbook::default]`, which in turn maps to `mycookbook/recipes/default.rb`. Similarly if you have `mycookbook/recipes/foo.rb` that would be `recipe[mycookbook::foo]`.